# complex SOAP request prints single line response

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am completely new to Python and Suds.In order to test different clients, I succeeded in C#, java, perl and now term is about Python-suds...can some one help...
here is the client code----

```
from suds.client import Client
wsdl = 'http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/ws/SignalP/SignalP_3_1_ws0.wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl)
seq="""val1
val2
val3"""
print client.service.runService(seq)
```

and sending request envelope is....

```
<parameters>
 <organism> val1
 </organism>
 <sequencedata>
       <sequence>
           <id>val2</id>
           <seq>val3</seq>
        </sequence>
  </sequencedata>
</parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer myself, but it seems it's not 100%; I am getting a correct response envelope, but the request envelope has incorrect formatting for `val2` and `val3`.

Here I put altogether (I used logging to know the input/ouput):

```
from suds.client import Client
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# soap messages (in&out) and http headers
wsdl = 'http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/ws/SignalP/SignalP_3_1_ws0.wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl, cache=None,)

seq = client.factory.create('ns1:sequence')
seq.id="XXXXX"
seq.seq="KBVGHGKLGKLGKHGJHG"

req = client.factory.create('ns1:method')
req.parameters.organism="val1"
req.parameters.sequencedata.sequence=seq; 
response = client.service.runService(req)
```

Comment: hmmm i dont get it, where you put the val2 and val3 there?